# How to retrieve json data result from mvc controllers

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to get the result json_encode from the controller. Here's the code

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-register", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl() + "/users/register",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
      name: $("#name").val(),
      email: $("#email-address").val(),
      password: $("#password").val(),
      confirm: $("#confirm-password").val(),
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (message) {
      console.log(message.responseText);
    },
  });
});
```

And here's the source code for the controller:

```
public function register () {

    $result = [];

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

      $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

      $data = [
        'name'                    => trim($_POST['name']),
        'email'                   => trim($_POST['email']),
        'password'                => trim($_POST['password']),
        'confirm_password'        => trim($_POST['confirm']),
        'name_error'              => '',
        'email_error'             => '',
        'password_error'          => '',
        'confirm_password_error'  => ''
      ];

      $data['name_error'] = (empty($data['name'])) ? 'Please enter name' : '';
      $data['confirm_password_error']  = (empty($data['confirm_password']))   ? 'Please confirm password' : '';

      if (empty($data['email']))
        $data['email_error'] = 'Please enter email';
      else if ($this->user->findUserByEmail($data['email']) === true)
        $data['email_error'] = 'Email is already taken';

      if (empty($data['password']))
        $data['password_error'] = 'Please enter a password';
      else if (strlen($data['password']) < self::$password_length)
        $data['password_error'] = 'Password must be at least ' . self::$password_length . ' characters long';
      else if ($data['password'] != $data['confirm_password'])
        $data['password_error'] = 'Password did not match';

      if (
          empty($data['name_error']) && 
          empty($data['email_error']) && 
          empty($data['password_error']) && 
          empty($data['confirm_password_error'])) {
        
          $result['status'] = 'valid inputs';
          echo json_encode($result);
      }

    } else {
      
      $data = [
        'name'                    => '',
        'email'                   => '',
        'password'                => '',
        'confirm_password'        => '',
        'name_error'              => '',
        'email_error'             => '',
        'password_error'          => '',
        'confirm_password_error'  => ''
      ];

    }

    $this->view('users/register', $data);
    
  }
```

I just test it out and whenever I click the **#btn-register** button, this is the result returned in the console.log from error: function (message):

```
{"status":"valid inputs"}<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://shareposts.localhost/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://shareposts.localhost/assets/bootstrap/icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://shareposts.localhost/css/style.css"/>

  <title>SharePost App</title>

  <script src="http://shareposts.localhost/js/base-url.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <header data-bs-theme="dark">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mb-5">

    <div class="container">

      <a href="http://shareposts.localhost" class="navbar-brand">

        <i class="bi bi-share-fill"></i>

      </a>

      <button 

        type="button"

        class="navbar-toggler" 

        data-bs-toggle="collapse" 

        data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" 

        aria-controls="navbarCollapse" 

        aria-expanded="false" 

        aria-label="Toggle navigation">

        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">

        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">

          <li class="nav-item">

            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="http://shareposts.localhost">Home</a>

          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">

            <a class="nav-link" href="http://shareposts.localhost/home/about">About</a>

          </li>

        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

          <li class="nav-item">

            <a class="nav-link" href="http://shareposts.localhost/users/login">Login</a>

          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">

            <a class="nav-link" href="http://shareposts.localhost/users/register">Register</a>

          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>

  </nav>

</header>  <div class="container">

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">

    <div class="card">

      <div class="card-body">

        <h2 class="card-title">Create an Account</h2>

        <p class="card-text">Please fill out this form to register with us</p>

        <form method="post">

          <div class="form-group mb-3">

            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name: <sup>*</sup></label>

            <input 

              type="text" 

              class="form-control " 

              id="name" 

              name="name"

              value="asdf" />

              <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group mb-3">

            <label for="email-address" class="form-label">Email address: <sup>*</sup></label>

            <input 

              type="email" 

              class="form-control " 

              id="email-address" 

              name="email-address" 

              aria-describedby="email-help"

              value="jdoe@gmail.com" />

              <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>

            <div id="email-help" class="form-text">

              We'll never share your email with anyone else.

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group mb-3">

            <label for="password" class="form-label">Password: <sup>*</sup></label>

            <input 

              type="password" 

              class="form-control " 

              id="password" 

              name="password"

              value="1234567" />

              <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group mb-3">

            <label for="confirm-password" class="form-label">Confirm Password: <sup>*</sup></label>

            <input 

              type="password" 

              class="form-control " 

              id="confirm-password" 

              name="confirm-password"

              value="1234567" />

              <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>

          </div>

          <div class="d-flex gap-2">

            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-success w-100" id="btn-register"/>

            <a href="http://shareposts.localhost/users/login" class="btn btn-light w-100">Have an account? Login</a>

          </div>

      </form>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>



  </div>

  <script src="http://shareposts.localhost/assets/jquery/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://shareposts.localhost/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html><script src="http://shareposts.localhost/js/users.js"></script>
```

It returns the whole html content file. Why is this and how can I resolve this error? I just only want the **valid input** from json_encode to be return but the problem is that the html content was also returned.

Comment: What does `$this->view('users/register', $data);` do? Possibly change `echo json_encode($result);` to `exit(json_encode($result));` but thats making assumptions.

Comment: $this->view('users/register', $data) - just calling the register page from users directory and passing that $data to the view.

Comment: Why do you need that? This is just the AJAX response page, right? Shouldn't have view code here. You also overwrite `$data` in your `else` so the specific error can't be served. (You error messages are giving too much info to possible hackers also)

Comment: Oh I seee. But I just need it so that I can still run the view.

Comment: You should have a unique page for the AJAX request.. or a custom event for serving  only the JSON back. So either `url: baseUrl() + "/users/register?request=ajax"` or `url: baseUrl() + "/users/register-ajax-request"` then create route and view for `register-ajax-request` which sends JSON only, or on this page check for `$_GET['request'] == 'ajax'` and then only serve the JSON.

Comment: You are trying to get only json response but you are getting whole html. 

For doing this you can define new url or route from where you will get json response. YOu can also use same page for html and json. In that case, you will have to pass on parameter such as ajax=true and catch that in method inside class. Then return all your response inside if condition with json_encode() results